# Axis2 wsdl2c not generating all calls in skeleton

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm using WSDL2C tool in axis2 to generate a C web service, and I noticed that a lot of the calls I've added are not having their respective calls being created in the skeleton files. It creates the old ones but not any of the new ones.

I'm creating the wsdl in eclipse, then using the command line tool with the command :

`WSDL2C.bat -uri mywsdl.wsdl -ss -sd -d adb -u`

When I run it it says retrieving WSDL file and nothing else. I'm quite confounded by this and it seems like there is a lack of information on the web for Axis2/C problems.

I created the calls by clicking on add operation in the eclipse visual editor and then filling in the elements. I'm pretty sure I shouldn't need to do anything else, but i might be mistaken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you have defined the new web service operations, but you didn't add them to the binding definitions. Bindings define how a web service operation is called through the SOAP (or whatever) interface.

Using the eclipse WSDL editor, click on the binding object and select "Generate Binding Content...".

Comment: You hit it straight on the nose. Fixed it perfectly thank you.